# How to select where left join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have query like this

```
SELECT tb_post.*, 
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tb_category.category_name) 
       FROM tb_category 
       LEFT JOIN tb_terms ON tb_terms.parent_1 = tb_category.category_id 
       WHERE tb_terms.post_id = `tb_post`.post_id and category_type="post" 
       GROUP BY tb_terms.post_id) AS parent1 
FROM (`tb_post`)
```

---

[image]

But this where is not run. This is always return all row in table.. I want add where why?

I do not want to change the shape query and i **I need all the data from tb_post but where tb_category.category_type=$value** and do not change the structure of the query

Comment: Unrelated to your main problem but your sub query uses a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but also checks the value from a column from the left joined table in the WHERE clause. As for any non matched column that will have a value of NULL it is unlikely to match against tb_post.post_id (which looks like a unique id). As such it renders it as effectively an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

if u not need tb_post.* then remove that because it call all data from database and if inner query get less record then tb.post then also it display max record(tb_post)

Comment: I need all the data from tb_post but where tb_category.category_type='$value'

Comment: yes , tb_terms.parent_1 is join tb_category ....
for this reference http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_relation_n_n

Comment: //Sorry Codeigniter but you cannot help me with the subquery!
$select .= ", (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT $field) FROM $selection_table "."LEFT JOIN $relation_table ON $relation_table.$primary_key_alias_to_selection_table = $selection_table.$primary_key_selection_table "."WHERE $relation_table.$primary_key_alias_to_this_table = `{$this->table_name}`.$this_table_primary_key $whereof GROUP BY $relation_table.$primary_key_alias_to_this_table) AS $field_name";

Comment: okay good now last question what u need ???? i think all data from tb_post and common data of category and tb_term (i mean id common ) m I right ????

Comment: yes i want filter return from the query data, Just return All tb_post data and tb_category data but where category_type is post/$value

Comment: the data from tb_post but where tb_category.category_type=$value

Comment: SELECT tb_post.*, parent1.categories
FROM tb_post
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT tb_terms.post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tb_category.category_name) AS categories
  FROM tb_category 
  LEFT JOIN tb_terms ON tb_terms.parent_1 = tb_category.category_id 
  WHERE tb_terms.post_id = tb_post.post_id and category_type="post" 
  GROUP BY tb_terms.post_id) parent1 ON tb_post.post_id = parent1.post_id

Comment: but this retun error #1054 - Unknown column 'tb_post.post_id' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Use INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT tb_post.*, tc.categories
FROM tb_post
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT tb_terms.post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tb_category.category_name) AS categories
  FROM tb_category 
  LEFT JOIN tb_terms ON tb_terms.parent_1 = tb_category.category_id 
  WHERE tb_category.category_type="post" 
  GROUP BY tb_terms.post_id
) tc ON tc.post_id = tb_post.post_id
```

Comment: hy Rimas. Thank you once , It was very helpful but I Have another problem HOW TO PUT your query to this function --> http://notepad.cc/share/ghmy0Ko78c

Comment: Your problem is unclear. The easiest way is to just return this query: `protected function relation_n_n_queries($select) { return "SELECT tb_post.* ... and rest of the query ..."; }`

Comment: RimasThank you very much . but code by you and than combained by @Kickstart is very good

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to modify your query as @Rimas suggests, but with the fragment of the function to generate that query I can't see enough to see how to do this.

If that is not possible then I would be tempted to somewhat abuse the HAVING clause and do something like this:-

```
SELECT tb_post.*, 
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tb_category.category_name) 
       FROM tb_category 
       INNER JOIN tb_terms ON tb_terms.parent_1 = tb_category.category_id 
       WHERE tb_terms.post_id = `tb_post`.post_id 
       AND category_type="post" 
       GROUP BY tb_terms.post_id) AS parent1 
FROM (`tb_post`)
HAVING parent1 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Good. It really helped me . Thank you very much . You have saved my life ^ _ ^